# click on a list item to get the relevant information from a JSON file to update the HTML with the correct data

Tags: javascript, json, loops

I'm looking to update the text content on the html page with the relevant information from the JSON file.

At the moment, I'm able to populate the drop down menu, with players name from the JSON file. But I'm not sure how to target a list item, when it has been clicked on and populate the players stats with the correct data from the JSON file.

Below is my code, any help or guidance would be great as I'm stuck for the past couple of days now.... Thanks in advance!

Here is the HTML

```
<body>
<section class="player-card">
    <!-- player-dropDown -->
    <div class="player-dropDown">
        <ul class="player-dropDown__disable">
            <li id="disable"> Select a player... </li>

            <ul class="player-dropDown__select">
                <li class="select"> Toby Alderweireld </li>
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <!-- player-img -->
    <div class="player-img">
        <img src="./img/toby.png">
    </div>

    <!-- player-stats -->
    <div class="player-stats">

        <h1 class="player-stats__name">Toby Alderweireld</h1>
        <h2 class="player-stats__position">Defender</h2>

        <div class="player-stats__badge">
            <div id="player-stats__badge-icon"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="player-stats__container">
            <div class="player-stats__box player-stats__box-space clear">
                <p class="player-stats__box-name"> Appearances </p>
                <p id ="appearances" class="player-stats__box-value"> 80 </p>
            </div>

            <div class="player-stats__box player-stats__box-space clear">
                <p class="player-stats__box-name"> Goals </p>
                <p id="goals" class="player-stats__box-value"> 5 </p>
            </div>

            <div class="player-stats__box player-stats__box-space clear">
                <p class="player-stats__box-name"> Assists </p>
                <p id="assists" class="player-stats__box-value"> 2 </p>
            </div>

            <div class="player-stats__box player-stats__box-space clear">
                <p class="player-stats__box-name"> Goals per match </p>
                <p id="goals-per-match" class="player-stats__box-value"> 0.06 </p>
            </div>

            <div class="player-stats__box clear">
                <p class="player-stats__box-name"> Passes per minute </p>
                <p id="passes-per-min" class="player-stats__box-value"> 0.26 </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
```

Here is my JS

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    // Parse JSON file from string to object
    var response, players;
    response = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
    players = response.players;

    // toggle menu
    function toggleMenu() {
        var DropDownBtn, DropDownMenu;
        DropDownBtn = document.getElementById('disable');
        DropDownMenu = document.querySelector('.player-dropDown__select');

        DropDownBtn.onclick = function() {
            DropDownMenu.classList.toggle('show');
            console.log('menu clicked');
        }
    }

    // dropDownNameOutput
    function menuNameOutput() {
        var menuNameOutput;
        menuNameOutput = '';

        // loop through JSON file
        for ( var i = 0; i < players.length; i++ ) {
            var playerID, 
            playerFirstName, 
            playerLastName, 
            appearance, 
            goals, 
            assists, 
            goalsPerMatch, 
            goalsPerMatchDecimal, 
            passesPerMin, 
            fwdPasses, 
            bwdPasses, 
            minsPlayed, 
            passesPerMinDecimal;

            // from the JSON file log the players stats
            playerID = players[i].player.id;
            playerFirstName = players[i].player.name.first;
            playerLastName = players[i].player.name.last;
            appearance = players[i].stats[6].value;
            goals = players[i].stats[0].value;
            assists = players[i].stats[5].value;
            fwdPasses = players[i].stats[4].value;
            bwdPasses = players[i].stats[8].value;
            minsPlayed = players[i].stats[7].value;
            goalsPerMatch = goals / appearance;
            goalsPerMatchDecimal = goalsPerMatch.toFixed(2);
            passesPerMin = (fwdPasses + bwdPasses) / minsPlayed;
            passesPerMinDecimal = passesPerMin.toFixed(2);


            // populate the drop down menu with players names & ID
            menuNameOutput += '<li id="' + playerID + '"' + ' ' + 'class="select">' + playerFirstName + ' ' + playerLastName + '</li>';
        };

        // output the players name & ID to the menu (HTML)
        document.querySelector('.player-dropDown__select').innerHTML = menuNameOutput;
    };

    toggleMenu();
    menuNameOutput();
}
};
xhttp.open("GET", "JSON/player-stats.json", true);
xhttp.send();
```

Here is the JSON

```
{  
"players":[  
    {  
        "player":{  
            "info":{  
                "position":"D",
                "shirtNum":4,
                "positionInfo":"Centre/Right Central Defender"
            },
            "nationalTeam":{  
                "isoCode":"BE",
                "country":"Belgium",
                "demonym":"Belgian"
            },
            "age":"27 years 139 days",
            "name":{  
                "first":"Toby",
                "last":"Alderweireld"
            },
            "id":4916,
            "currentTeam":{  
                "name":"Tottenham Hotspur",
                "teamType":"FIRST",
                "shortName":"Spurs",
                "id":21
            }
        },
        "stats":[  
            {  
                "name":"goals",
                "value":5
            },
            {  
                "name":"losses",
                "value":20
            },
            {  
                "name":"wins",
                "value":48
            },
            {  
                "name":"draws",
                "value":23
            },
            {  
                "name":"fwd_pass",
                "value":1533
            },
            {  
                "name":"goal_assist",
                "value":2
            },
            {  
                "name":"appearances",
                "value":80
            },
            {  
                "name":"mins_played",
                "value":6953
            },
            {  
                "name":"backward_pass",
                "value":308
            }
        ]
    },
    {  
        "player":{  
            "info":{  
                "position":"M",
                "shirtNum":42,
                "positionInfo":"Centre Defensive Midfielder"
            },
            "nationalTeam":{  
                "isoCode":"CI",
                "country":"Cote D'Ivoire",
                "demonym":"Ivorian"
            },
            "age":"33 years 67 days",
            "name":{  
                "first":"Yaya",
                "last":"Touré"
            },
            "id":4148,
            "currentTeam":{  
                "name":"Manchester City",
                "teamType":"FIRST",
                "shortName":"Man City",
                "id":11
            }
        },
        "stats":[  
            {  
                "name":"goals",
                "value":65
            },
            {  
                "name":"losses",
                "value":49
            },
            {  
                "name":"wins",
                "value":149
            },
            {  
                "name":"draws",
                "value":35
            },
            {  
                "name":"fwd_pass",
                "value":4491
            },
            {  
                "name":"goal_assist",
                "value":35
            },
            {  
                "name":"appearances",
                "value":232
            },
            {  
                "name":"mins_played",
                "value":18919
            },
            {  
                "name":"backward_pass",
                "value":1995
            }
        ]
    },
    {  
        "player":{  
            "info":{  
                "position":"F",
                "shirtNum":10,
                "positionInfo":"Left/Centre/Right Second Striker"
            },
            "nationalTeam":{  
                "isoCode":"GB-ENG",
                "country":"England",
                "demonym":"English"
            },
            "age":"30 years 269 days",
            "name":{  
                "first":"Wayne",
                "last":"Rooney"
            },
            "id":2064,
            "currentTeam":{  
                "name":"Manchester United",
                "teamType":"FIRST",
                "shortName":"Man Utd",
                "id":12
            }
        },
        "stats":[  
            {  
                "name":"goals",
                "value":201
            },
            {  
                "name":"losses",
                "value":91
            },
            {  
                "name":"wins",
                "value":280
            },
            {  
                "name":"draws",
                "value":90
            },
            {  
                "name":"fwd_pass",
                "value":1795
            },
            {  
                "name":"goal_assist",
                "value":84
            },
            {  
                "name":"appearances",
                "value":461
            },
            {  
                "name":"mins_played",
                "value":27056
            },
            {  
                "name":"backward_pass",
                "value":1928
            }
        ]
    },
    {  
        "player":{  
            "info":{  
                "position":"D",
                "shirtNum":4,
                "positionInfo":"Centre Central Defender"
            },
            "nationalTeam":{  
                "isoCode":"DE",
                "country":"Germany",
                "demonym":"German"
            },
            "age":"31 years 294 days",
            "name":{  
                "first":"Per",
                "last":"Mertesacker"
            },
            "id":4246,
            "currentTeam":{  
                "name":"Arsenal",
                "teamType":"FIRST",
                "shortName":"Arsenal",
                "id":1
            }
        },
        "stats":[  
            {  
                "name":"goals",
                "value":8
            },
            {  
                "name":"losses",
                "value":45
            },
            {  
                "name":"wins",
                "value":117
            },
            {  
                "name":"draws",
                "value":41
            },
            {  
                "name":"fwd_pass",
                "value":4257
            },
            {  
                "name":"goal_assist",
                "value":0
            },
            {  
                "name":"appearances",
                "value":187
            },
            {  
                "name":"mins_played",
                "value":16531
            },
            {  
                "name":"backward_pass",
                "value":535
            }
        ]
    },
    {  
        "player":{  
            "info":{  
                "position":"M",
                "shirtNum":26,
                "positionInfo":"Left/Right Winger"
            },
            "nationalTeam":{  
                "isoCode":"DZ",
                "country":"Algeria",
                "demonym":"Algerian"
            },
            "age":"25 years 149 days",
            "name":{  
                "first":"Riyad",
                "last":"Mahrez"
            },
            "id":8983,
            "currentTeam":{  
                "name":"Leicester City",
                "teamType":"FIRST",
                "shortName":"Leicester",
                "id":26
            }
        },
        "stats":[  
            {  
                "name":"goals",
                "value":22
            },
            {  
                "name":"losses",
                "value":23
            },
            {  
                "name":"wins",
                "value":35
            },
            {  
                "name":"draws",
                "value":21
            },
            {  
                "name":"fwd_pass",
                "value":687
            },
            {  
                "name":"goal_assist",
                "value":14
            },
            {  
                "name":"appearances",
                "value":71
            },
            {  
                "name":"mins_played",
                "value":5368
            },
            {  
                "name":"backward_pass",
                "value":323
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

Comment: Can you post the sample JSON.

Comment: Hi @Bibberty I've added the JSON file, thanks for taking a look at this :)

Comment: So taking a look at this, it will need some work. The drop down should be a select and we should probably use a template for the player output. Will work on this in Repl before we post an answer here ok.

Comment: Thank you for your help @Bibberty.... I really appreciate it! :)

Comment: There's a lot going on in your problem statement: "I'm not sure how to target a list item, when it has been clicked on and populate the players stats with the correct data from the JSON file." Could you specify which of these you're having trouble with?: 1) Listening for clicks on a particular `<li>` element; 2) Accessing the contents of a separate (JSON) file; 3) Extracting the relevant values from the JSON string; and/or 4) Updating the `<li>`'s contents with these values

Comment: Hi @Cat I’m able to access the JSON file, but having trouble with 1 & then trying to populate the player stats with the correct data from the JSON file. Thanks for helping me with this :)

Comment: Are you free to restructure the JSON? And would you mind if I proposed a solution that requires doing so?

Comment: Yes I'm free to restructure the JSON, and please propose a solution, thanks.

Comment: Great. I have to be offline for a few hours, but I'll finalize my answer and post my it when I get back on.

Comment: Work in progress - https://repl.it/@PaulThomas1/AnswerStackFlowJSON @Cat feel free to fork. Agree, the JSON could be changed.

Comment: Take a look. Its working on the Repl. Some things to fix. Where are the images, needs CSS styling etc.

Comment: Hi Bibberty and Cat.  Thank you both for your help! I used the example from Bibberty and was able to adapt it to add more functionality.  Thank you both again, for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example code you can paste into the body element of an html file. 
It contains only two players for simplicity.

The HTML employs a `select` element, each of whose `option` children has a player's full name as its visible `text` and that player's playerId as its invisible `value`.
Selecting an option triggers a function that:
1)uses the playerId to find the corresponding player data in the global `players` object,
2)stores that data in the global `selectedPlayer` object, and
3)demonatrates how to retrieve specific values from that selectedPlayer.
(Retrieving values -- including the player objects, which use the player's playerId as their keys -- is made a bit simpler by the fact that the JSON contains no arrays, only objects.)

```
<select id="dropdown" onchange="respondToSelection()">
  <option value="0000">Some Player</option>
  <option value="4246">Per Mertesacker</option>
</select>

<script>
  // Global identifiers
  const
    dropdown = document.querySelector("#dropdown"),
    opts = dropdown.options,
    jsonString = getJsonString(),
    players = JSON.parse(jsonString); // Javascript object containing all players' info
  let selectedPlayer; // Object will hold info for whichever player is selected

  function respondToSelection(){
    // Handles user input by populating the selectedPlayer object with the corresponding data
    const
      index = dropdown.selectedIndex,
      selected = opts[index],
      text = selected.text,
      playerId = selected.value;
    console.log(`text from dropdown: ${text}`);
    console.log(`playerId from dropdown: ${playerId}`);

    selectedPlayer = players[playerId]; // Stores the selected player's info in the selectedPlayer object

    // Now we can get any property within the selected player by using dot notation like:
    const
      country = selectedPlayer.player.nationalTeam.country,
      goals = selectedPlayer.stats.goals;
    console.log(`country: ${country}`);
    console.log(`goals: ${goals}`);
  }

  function getJsonString(){
    return `{
      "4246" : {
        "player": {
        "info": { "position" : "D", "shirtNum" : 4, "positionInfo" : "Centre Central Defender" },
        "nationalTeam": { "isoCode" : "DE", "country" : "Germany", "demonym" : "German" },
        "age": "31 years 294 days",
        "name": { "first" : "Per", "last" : "Mertesacker" },
        "id": "4246",
        "currentTeam": { "name" : "Arsenal", "teamType" : "FIRST", "shortName" : "Arsenal", "id" : 1 }
      },
      "stats": {
        "goals" : 8,
        "losses" : 45,
        "wins" : 117,
        "draws" : 41,
        "fwd_pass" : 4257,
        "goal_assist" : 0,
        "appearances" : 187,
        "mins_played" : 16531,
        "backward_pass" : 535
      }
    },
    "0000" : {
      "player": {
        "info": { "position" : "D", "shirtNum" : 0, "positionInfo" : "Some Position" },
        "nationalTeam": { "isoCode" : "DE", "country" : "Germany", "demonym" : "German" },
        "age": "29 years 29 days",
        "name": { "first" : "Some", "last" : "Player" },
        "id": "0000",
        "currentTeam": { "name" : "Arsenal", "teamType" : "FIRST", "shortName" : "Arsenal", "id" : 1 }
      },
      "stats": {
        "goals" : 1,
        "losses" : 1,
        "wins" : 1,
        "draws" : 1,
        "fwd_pass" : 57,
        "goal_assist" : 0,
        "appearances" : 18,
        "mins_played" : 531,
        "backward_pass" : 35
      }
    }
  }`
}
</script>
```